# Update android contact's email programmatically

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have a contact with only phone number and  name.

Now I want to update contact and ADD E-mail information.

what I do -

```
 public void updateMail(String name, String mail) {
        ContentResolver cr = mcontext.getContentResolver();
        String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " +
               ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
               String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";

        String[] params = new String[] {name,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                 String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)};

        Cursor phoneCur =   
               mcontext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,   
               null, where, params, null);
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new  
               ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        if ( (null == phoneCur)  ) {
        //createContact(name, phone);
            Log.e(TAG, "null == phoneCur");

         } else {

         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                     .withSelection(where, params)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, mail)
                     .build());
       }

         phoneCur.close();

         try {
            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It works only if I ALREADY HAVE contact with e-mail field.
If I don't have it -  nothing happens.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ((null == phoneCur))`, In this code you have checked if Contact information is present or not. If it is `null (No contact)` then you have missed the `ops.add()` code.

You either remove this condition `if ((null == phoneCur))` or add 'ops.add()' in the 'if' block.